# Use of the `\underbrace` in a `TikZ` environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code renders a graph of three vertices and three edges. (Nothing exciting.) Between the first vertex and the second vertex, I want to convey that there may be `n - 1` more vertices. The second "displayed" vertex may actually be the nth vertex. I am getting error messages with my use of the `\underbrace` command. I am using it within a node command. I think this is allowed within a node command. Can `\mathrlap` be used within a node command? Should any of this be coded in math mode?

I may want to have a longer text under the brace - like "$n+1$ more vertices may be here but that is for me to know and you to find out." How would I typeset that on two or three lines?

In a graph, what is the convention regarding edges between consecutive "displayed" vertices when there may be more to the graph between them? Do I draw part of an edge off of each vertex? Do I typeset ellipses in the middle between the two "displayed" vertices? Do I typeset a pair of ellipses between the "displayed" vertices - one ellipses next to each vertex?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools} %Loads amsmath


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path (0,0) coordinate (vertex_1) (3,0) coordinate (vertex_n) (5,0) coordinate (vertex_n+1);
\draw[fill] (vertex_1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (vertex_n) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (vertex_n+1) circle (1.5pt);

\draw (vertex_1) -- ($(vertex_1) +(0.75,0)$);
\draw (vertex_n) -- ($(vertex_n) +(-0.75,0)$) -- (vertex_n+1);

\coordinate (midpoint) at ($($(vertex_1) +(0.75,0)$)!0.5!($(vertex_n) +(-0.75,0)$)$);
\coordinate (brace) at ($(midpoint) +(0,-0.75)$);
%\node at (brace){\mathrlap{\underbrace{\phantom{n + 1\text{ more vertices}}}_{text}}};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It is usable inside a node, but you must use it inside math mode.

Comment: I just added the following command, and it compiles. Thanks.

Comment: `\node at (brace){$\mathrlap{\underbrace{\phantom{n + 1\text{ more vertices}}}_{n + 1\text{ more vertices}}}$};`

Comment: If your graph is a Dynkin diagram, or looks like one, you might try the dynkin-diagrams package on CTAN, which has built in support for braces between vertices and for dots to indicate indefinitely many vertices omitted: https://ctan.org/pkg/dynkin-diagrams?lang=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Between the first vertex and the second vertex, I want to convey that there may be n - 1 more vertices. The second "displayed" vertex may actually be the nth vertex. I am getting error messages with my use of the \underbrace command. I am using it within a node command. I think this is allowed within a node command. Can \mathrlap be used within a node command? Should any of this be coded in math mode?

You need to put `\underbrace`, etc. inside math mode for it to work (I don't know if this is the intended output)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools} %Loads amsmath
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) coordinate (vertex_1) (3,0) coordinate (vertex_n) (5,0) coordinate (vertex_n+1);
\draw[fill] (vertex_1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (vertex_n) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (vertex_n+1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (vertex_1) -- ($(vertex_1) +(0.75,0)$);
\draw (vertex_n) -- ($(vertex_n) +(-0.75,0)$) -- (vertex_n+1);
\coordinate (midpoint) at ($($(vertex_1) +(0.75,0)$)!0.5!($(vertex_n) +(-0.75,0)$)$);
\coordinate (brace) at ($(midpoint) +(0,-0.75)$);
\node at (brace){$\mathrlap{\underbrace{\phantom{n + 1\text{ more vertices}}}_{text}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

> I may want to have a longer text under the brace - like "$n+1$ more vertices may be here but that is for me to know and you to find out." How would I typeset that on two or three lines?

My recommended version with automatic line breaks:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) coordinate (vertex_1) (3,0) coordinate (vertex_n) (5,0) coordinate (vertex_n+1);
\draw[fill] (vertex_1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (vertex_n) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (vertex_n+1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (vertex_1) -- ($(vertex_1) +(0.75,0)$);
\draw (vertex_n) -- ($(vertex_n) +(-0.75,0)$) -- (vertex_n+1);
\coordinate (midpoint) at ($($(vertex_1) +(0.75,0)$)!0.5!($(vertex_n) +(-0.75,0)$)$);
\node (x) at (midpoint) {$\cdots$};
\node[draw,font=\footnotesize,text width=3cm] (callout) at (2,-2) {$n+1$ more vertices may be here but that is for me to know and you to find out.};
\draw[->] (callout) -- (x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or with manual line breaks:

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) coordinate (vertex_1) (3,0) coordinate (vertex_n) (5,0) coordinate (vertex_n+1);
\draw[fill] (vertex_1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (vertex_n) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (vertex_n+1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw (vertex_1) -- ($(vertex_1) +(0.75,0)$);
\draw (vertex_n) -- ($(vertex_n) +(-0.75,0)$) -- (vertex_n+1);
\coordinate (midpoint) at ($($(vertex_1) +(0.75,0)$)!0.5!($(vertex_n) +(-0.75,0)$)$);
\node (x) at (midpoint) {$\cdots$};
\node[draw,font=\footnotesize,align=center] (callout) at (2,-2) {$n+1$ more vertices may\\be here but that is for me to\\know and you to find out.};
\draw[->] (callout) -- (x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

> In a graph, what is the convention regarding edges between consecutive "displayed" vertices when there may be more to the graph between them? Do I draw part of an edge off of each vertex? Do I typeset ellipses in the middle between the two "displayed" vertices? Do I typeset a pair of ellipses between the "displayed" vertices - one ellipses next to each vertex?

This question does not fall within the scope of TeX, LaTeX or related typesetting systems as defined in the help center.

Comment: The option `text width=3cm` instructs `TikZ` to typeset text on more lines ... if needed. I have a request to modify to your code. How do I center the text? This is important in case I use \\ to artificially break a line.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire Then you have options `align=center` and \\. However, I thought you were looking for `text width`.

Comment: OK. I have two options: `\text width=3cm` or `align=center`. With the second option, I would have to use \\.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will typeset the code that I think that I want later tonight. If I don't have any other requests for modification, I will "accept" your answer tomorrow.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire It is very late here and I also have to go to bed, so if you have any requests, please ask tomorrow :))

Comment: I am tying to modify your first code - the one with the underbrace. I would like to have "n+1 more" above "vertices" and both typeset in `\footnotesize`.

Comment: May you modify it for me?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire It is a math mode question, not related to Ti*k*Z anymore. You can use `array` to fake the line break.

Comment: I used the following command, and it typesets the text properly.

Comment: `\node[font=\footnotesize, anchor=north, inner sep=0, align=center] at (center_of_brace){\mbox{$n + 1$ more} \\
{\mbox{vertices}}};`

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools} %Loads amsmath


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path (0,0) coordinate (vertex_1) (3,0) coordinate (vertex_n) (5,0) coordinate (vertex_n+1);
\draw[fill] (vertex_1) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (vertex_n) circle (1.5pt);
\draw[fill] (vertex_n+1) circle (1.5pt);

\draw (vertex_1) -- ($(vertex_1) +(0.75,0)$);
\draw (vertex_n) -- ($(vertex_n) +(-0.75,0)$) -- (vertex_n+1);

\coordinate (midpoint) at ($(vertex_1)!0.5!(vertex_n)$);
\coordinate (center_of_brace) at ($(midpoint) +(0,-0.75)$);
\node[font=\footnotesize, anchor=north, inner sep=0, align=center] at (center_of_brace){\mbox{$n + 1$ more} \\
{\mbox{vertices}}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```